# Sims city Minimizing the tab

Tags: the-sims

I know how to get it off full screen mode and on to tab mode but then its to long so I can't access some of the controls, how can I minimize the tab so that it fits, i'm going to record it for a series so I need it on tab mode to stop the recording if I need to.

Answer (score 1):

Change the game resolution to something smaller than your desktop resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Options and find something that says Fullscreen. Uncheck that box, and the game should be in a normal Window's tab. After that set the gam resolution to fit your desktop tab.